# Base 5 help! determine if the solution is correct or incorrect

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binary

Okay so the question is : 
Below is a solution for rewriting/representing 321(five) in a different way. Determine if the solution is correct or incorrect and why (by relating it to the original number). 
1(five) flat, 12(five) rods, 101(five) small squares

This is really confusing to me, base-5 really messes with my head. I have been working on this problem for 4 hours. Every time I come up with an explanation, I read it and it does not make any sense. Please help! :(

Comment: What is a flat, a rod, a small square?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I can’t see exactly what the question is. What is “flat”, what “rod”, what “small squares”?

Comment: it’s using manipulatives. it’s the plastic pieces kids use when they’re learning how to add/subtract. so in base 10, a small square would be 1, a rod would be 10, a flat would be 100. but in base 5, a small square is 1, a rod is 5 and a flat is 25.

Comment: Well, I’m sure you understand that $321_5$ is $1+2\cdot5+3\cdot25$, thus eighty-six, right?

Comment: I somewhat understand that. This is the first time I have ever seen base-5. I get it, but it confuses me very easily. especially how this question has 12 and 101 considering those “don’t exist” in base-5. we aren’t allowed to use base-10 at all in our answer which makes it difficult.

Comment: You can solve it using base 5 additions: a "flat" is $100_5$, a rod $10_5$ and a square $1_5$. Now $1_5*100_5=100_5$, $12_5*10_5=120_5$, $101_5*1_5=101_5$ and $100_5+120_5+101_5=321_5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this easier, first look at the number $325$ in standard base $10$. 
One can clearly see that
$$325=100\cdot 3+10\cdot 2 +1\cdot 5$$
Or in other words, three $10$ "flats", two $10$ "rods", and five "small squares". 
However in base $5$, the "flats" are $25=5^2$, the "rods" are $5=5^1$, and the "small squares" are $1=5^0$. 
Thus, in base $5$, 
\begin{align*}
1\space\text{base five"flats"}+&12\space\text{base five "rods"}+101\space\text{base five "small squares"}
\\ & =1\cdot (25)+12\cdot(5)+101\cdot (1)
\\ & =25+60+101=186\neq 325
\end{align*}

Which shows that this representation does not add up to $325$, and thus the solution is incorrect.

Comment: But everything is in base five, so $321_5=86$, $1_5=1$, $12_5=7$, $101_5=26$ (numbers on RHS are all in decimal representation). So $86=1*25+7*5+26*1$ and the solution is correct!

Comment: @N74 Ah yes I totally overlooked that fact, you are correct.